# Select Items not showing after form appends

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

The Select Items in my code below works if I havent added a new row yet.
The items are fetched from a db using php mysql.
How Can I still make the select options in the children elements work like the parent element cloned. The select button works like its disabled in the children element
I want the children element to also have the room to select items

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function create_tr(table_id) {
    let table_body = document.getElementById(table_id),
        first_tr = table_body.firstElementChild
    tr_clone = first_tr.cloneNode(true);

    table_body.append(tr_clone);

    clean_first_tr(table_body.firstElementChild);
}

function clean_first_tr(firstTr) {
    let children = firstTr.children;

    children = Array.isArray(children) ? children : Object.values(children);
    children.forEach(x => {
        if (x !== firstTr.lastElementChild) {
            x.firstElementChild.value = '';
        }
    });
}



function remove_tr(This) {
    if (This.closest('tbody').childElementCount == 1) {
        alert("First Row Can't Be Deleted");
    } else {
        This.closest('tr').remove();
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<div class="col-xl-8 col-md-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3 class="card-title">Add Device Information</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form id="" method="POST" autocomplete="off" novalidate="novalidate">
        <table class="table border text-nowrap text-md-nowrap table-striped mb-0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Device Model</th>
              <th>Serial No</th>
              <th>
                <button type="button" id="add" class=" btn text-success" onclick="create_tr('table_body')">
                  <i class="fe fe-plus-circle" id="add" style="font-size:1.6em;"></i>
                </button>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="field_wrapper" id="table_body">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control form-select select2" data-bs-placeholder="Select" name="model[]" required="" id="model"> <?php 
                                $readALL1 = "SELECT * FROM productmodels WHERE deleted = 0";
                                $displayAll1 = mysqli_query($conn,$readALL1);
                                while($rowFetchAll1 = mysqli_fetch_array($displayAll1)){
                                    $modelName = $rowFetchAll1['modelName'];
                                    $modelid = $rowFetchAll1['modelID'];
                              ?> <option value="
                                        <?=$modelid?>"> <?=$modelName?> </option> <?php } ?> </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="" name="" class="form-control" placeholder="Serial No...">
                <input type="text" name="addedBy[]" class="form-control" id="addedBy" value="
                                        <?=$_SESSION['user_uniq_id']?>" hidden="">
                <input type="text" name="client[]" class="form-control" value="
                                            <?=$clientID?>" id="client" hidden="">
                <input type="text" name="deviceID[]" class="form-control" value="
                                                <?=time()?>" id="deviceID" hidden="">
              </td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" id="add" class=" btn text-danger" onclick="remove_tr(this)">
                  <i class="fe fe-minus-circle" id="add" style="font-size:1.6em;"></i>
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put that in a fiddle

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ - just fill in the code

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky https://jsfiddle.net/sy16pwr5/

Comment: you have multiple elements sharing the same ID and then try to add even more...

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius  I have used your method but still same. I have taken out all the extra ID's .
If I use static options in the select menu it works fine. But once I try to call the items from a DB it doesn't work. it only fucntions like the old bug I am getting. ie select options not working in cloned children elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment I made above, you have duplicate IDs so whenever you use `document.getElementByID` you are going to have issues if attempting to call an element that has it's ID duplicated.

Fo the `delete` buttons to work you can either assign the event handler explicitly when you make the clone of the entire table row or the preferred method is to use a `delegated event handler` that intercepts click events to the common parent ( the table is easy ) and then reacts accordingly. The following HTML is a modified version of the above - all IDs have been removed, some replaced with dataset attributes. The `select` menu simply has a basic statically written few options to illustrate the case.

```js
// No element in the HTML now has an ID so there will be no duplicate IDs. To identify
// DOM elements a more useful set of selectors (querySelector & querySelectorAll) are
// very useful. The `event` can be used to begin DOM traversal to find elements of 
// interest rather than rely upon a static ID or crudely constructed dynamic IDs, usually
// involving numbers.
document.querySelector('button[data-name="add"]').addEventListener('click', e => {
  // from the event.target, find the parent table row and from that the table-body
  let tbody = e.target.closest('table').querySelector('tbody');
  // clone the first row from table-body and do some manipulations
  let clone=tbody.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
      clone.querySelector('button[data-name="del"]').hidden=false;
      clone.querySelectorAll('input, select').forEach(n=>{
        n.value='';
      });
  // add the new row - no IDS anywhere.
  tbody.appendChild(clone);
  
});

// Delegated Event Listener. This is bound to the table and monitors `click` events
// but processes only those events originating from the specified elements (button & i)
// - newly added elements are not registered in the DOM when the page loads initially
// which is why a delegated listener is used.
document.querySelector('form table#dyntbl').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // only process clicks from either a button with dataset.name='del' or it's child i
  if (e.target != e.currentTarget && (e.target.dataset.name == 'del' || e.target.parentNode.dataset.name == 'del')) {
    // identify the table-body as before
    let tbody = e.target.closest('table').querySelector('tbody');
    // remove table row unless it is the 1st one otherwise things break.
    if( tbody.childNodes.length > 3 ) tbody.removeChild(e.target.closest('tr') )
    
  }
});
```

```html
<div class='col-xl-8 col-md-12'>
  <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>
      <h3 class='card-title'>Add Device Information</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='card-body'>
      <form method='POST' autocomplete='off' novalidate='novalidate'>
        <table id='dyntbl' class='table border text-nowrap text-md-nowrap table-striped mb-0'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Device Model</th>
              <th>Serial No</th>
              <th>
                <button type='button' data-name='add' class=' btn text-success'>
                    <i class='fe fe-plus-circle' data-id='add' style='font-size:1.6em;'>#Add#</i>
                </button>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class='field_wrapper'>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class='form-control form-select select2' data-bs-placeholder='Select' name='model[]' required>
                  <option>A
                  <option>B
                  <option>C
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type='text' name='serial[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Serial No...' />
                <input type='text' name='addedBy[]' class='form-control' hidden />
                <input type='text' name='client[]' class='form-control' hidden />
                <input type='text' name='deviceID[]' class='form-control' hidden />
              </td>
              <td>
                <button type='button' data-name='del' class='btn text-danger' hidden>
                   <i class='fe fe-minus-circle' style='font-size:1.6em;'>#Delete#</i>
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used your method but still same. I have taken out all the extra ID's .
 But once I try to call the items from a DB it doesn't work. it only fucntions like the old bug I am getting. ie select options not working in cloned children elements.

Comment: I have found the solution.
@professor Abronsius
<select class='form-control form-select select2' data-bs-placeholder='Select' name='model[]' required>
I had to remove the select2 class.
that what was causing the problem..
Your solution worked better.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to offer a little help and that your problem is now solved.

Comment: after submitting form with ajax how do I remove the children elements. currently after form sumbission, the form resets but all children elements are still there still i manually delete them

Comment: By what method is the form submitted - is it a regular submit or ajax? If it is a regular type `submit` then you would need to use PHP to render/not render the form elements ( a session cookie might be useful for this ) whereas for an ajax type request the callback could easily remove all form elements ( or simply disable them all so the layout stays the same but functionality goes )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328995/clear-appended-fields-after-ajax-success
I am using ajax to submit the form

Comment: As you have not included the javascript that handles the ajax request all I can say is that you use the success callback to manipulate the DOM by either deleting, hiding or disabling these form elements

Comment: the link I attached in the previous comment actually has it.
but i have it here too. you can please access it and see the ajax I wrote.
I tried using the remove() in ajax after success but it didn't really work. it removed the parent element too.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328995/clear-appended-fields-after-ajax-success

Comment: it should be easy - perhaps like `[...document.querySelector('form').elements].forEach(n=>n.disabled=true)` or similar